# White-labelling an ASP.NET webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET webapp that business customers in India wish to purchase and run within their premises (it's for industrial use). What's my best approach to do this, but not lose control of my IP? Some concerns I had:

- Does ASP.NET4 code still need to get obfuscated to protect against reverse engineering, and how would this be done?
- Do I need to create a separate build specific to each customer that is restricted in some manner (eg. tied to physical box attributes such as CPU)?
- Is it possible for me to be the sole admin on the box, but give remote access to the folders that contain my CSS and HTML. That way I can maintain control over the code, but give the limited access the custom needs to customize the webapp to their site's look and feel. (Would large companies even accept this idea?)

Of-course, the other question is, am I better off not selling a white-label of the webapp altogether...

Comment: I like #3, but give your users a Control Panel, that would allow them to customize the app themselves using a web interface instead of access to the folders.

Comment: I'm not sure what the right answer is, but I'm 100% sure that #2 is the *wrong* answer.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a control panel to modify HTML and CSS??

Comment: you can code an app that way.  Many whitebox apps are [skinnable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at a software licensing and protection solution like http://www.inishtech.com/.

I dont know how good they are, but its a spinoff from one of Microsoft's divisions so they should be having good support for .net apps.

Being the sole admin on the box is just not a feasible solution for a software vendor. Its like if Microsoft was saying - 'hey you can buy Windows, but only I can change the admin password on your machine'. In fact if there is any information worth storing that the Businesses are going to put in there, they would want to ensure that you DO NOT have any access to their data.

Comment: The last comment totally depends on the context, which we know nothing about.

Comment: I think it is the general rule - when it comes to personal apps its the privacy issue, whereas when it comes to enterprise app, its about protecting business critical secrets. Unless the box does not store customer information inside of it, and is just used to process data and then dump it into customer's hard drive, i dont see an exception.